# How to solve system of equations

Tags: vectors

Hello I got this system om equations that I need to solve

$5y+w=1$

$2x+5y-4z+w=1$

I then multiply the first equation with -1 and then add it to the second equation and get 
$2x-4z=0$

$x=2z$

But then I do not know how to continue. According to book I should be able to see that this has infinite many solutions from here but I do not know how to see how many solutions it has right now. How do I know this?

Comment: How do you want to have help if you don't tell us what the unknowns are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see there are infinitely many solutions because you have simplified the equations to $$x=2z,w=1-5y$$ and you can then choose arbitrary values for $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0):

The system actually degenerates in two independent equations,

$$5y+w=1$$ and $$2x-4z=0$$

which are both single equations in two unknowns, each with an infinity of solutions.